# on screen keyboard not visible on mobile with Editors like Tinymce

Tags: javascript, iframe, tinymce-3

I have an issue with editors when writing comment from mobile devices that on touch start in iframe that generated from editor keyboard, not show

I tried to console touch start event it's worked well in all page except editor

```
document.addEventListener("touchstart", "iframe", function() {console.log('touched');});
```